# Regular expression getting two words from a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

With regular expressions how would I get two phrases from a sentence with this kind of structure

"change my **pain level** to **3**"

be able to build a system so it detects a pattern "change my" - and provides suitable hints from an array - let fieldNameArray = ["pain level", "swelling", "wound opening"]

then depending on the found first word(s) predict suitable values from another array
"change my **pain level** to "  let fieldOptions = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

in finding the two phrases from this pattern create a json object

let obj = {"name": "pain level", "value": "3"}

current jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/uftqp25r/

---

my current script looks like this

```
  textAnalysis(text){
    console.log("text", text);
    var fieldNames = ["swelling", "pain level", "wound opening"];
    let matchNames = fieldNames.join("|");
    console.log("matchNames", matchNames);

    let regEx = "(?:\\b|')("+matchNames+")(?:\\b|')";

    console.log("regEx", regEx)


    const found = text.match(regEx);

    console.log(found);


    let firstTriggerregEx = "(?:\\b|')(change my)(?:\\b|')";
    const found2 = text.match(firstTriggerregEx);
    console.log(found2);

    if(found2[0]){
      //show list of fielnames as hints
      console.log("show list of fieldnames as hints", fieldNames)
    }

     //if(pattern found - change my xxxx to)
    //{
        //show list of options for fieldname as hints
        //get xxxx options/values min/max range

        //if dropdown/radio/checkbox types
        //var fieldValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

        //if min/max -- loop to make array etc..

        //otherwise treat as open text - no prediction to give
    //}   

    //if(pattern found - change my xxxx to yyyy)
    //{
        // what is xxxx -- and what is yyy
        //if valid return object


        //var fieldValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
        //let matchValues = fieldValues.join("|");
        //console.log("matchValues", matchValues);

        //let regExValues = "(?:\\b|')("+matchValues+")(?:\\b|')";
        //const foundValMatch = "yyyyy".match(regEx);
        //console.log(foundValMatch);

        //valid fieldname and valid value
        

        //let obj = {"name": xxxx, "value": yyyy}
        
    //}

  }
```

this currently returns

"['pain level', 'pain level', index: 20, input: 'I want to change my pain level to 3 please', groups: undefined]"

--
I would have a form schema that contains ALL field labels, names and values, so it would be useful to push this into the function

```
let schema3 = {
  "id": "myform3",
  "initialValues": {
    "swelling" : 5,
    "pain_level" : 2,
    "wound_opening" : [],
    "healthy_regrowth_of_skin" : [],
    "throbbing" : [],
    "smelly_discharge" : [],
    "discolouration" : "2",
    "describe_your_symptoms_here" : "xxx",
  },
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "slider",
      "name": "swelling",
      "label": "Swelling",
      "min": 1,
      "max": 5,
      "validation": yup.number().required("slider is required"),
    },
    {
      "type": "slider",
      "name": "pain_level",
      "label": "Pain level",
      "min": 1,
      "max": 5,
      "validation": yup.number().required("slider is required"),
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "name": "wound_opening",
      "label": "Wound opening",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Yes",
          "value": "0",
          //"disabled": true
        }
      ],
      //"validation": yup.mixed().test('arraySize', "Must have at least one checked", value => value.length > 0),
      //"disabled": true          
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "name": "healthy_regrowth_of_skin",
      "label": "Healthy regrowth of skin",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Yes",
          "value": "0",
          //"disabled": true
        }
      ],
      //"validation": yup.mixed().test('arraySize', "Must have at least one checked", value => value.length > 0),
      //"disabled": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "name": "throbbing",
      "label": "Throbbing",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Yes",
          "value": "0",
          //"disabled": true
        }
      ],
      //"validation": yup.mixed().test('arraySize', "Must have at least one checked", value => value.length > 0),
      //"disabled": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "name": "smelly_discharge",
      "label": "Smelly discharge",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Yes",
          "value": "0",
          //"disabled": true
        }
      ],
      //"validation": yup.mixed().test('arraySize', "Must have at least one checked", value => value.length > 0),
      //"disabled": true
    },
    {
      //"disabled": true,
      "type": "select",
      "name": "discolouration",
      "label": "Discolouration",
      "options": [
        {
          "label": "Yellow",
          "value": "1"
        },{
          "label": "Red",
          "value": "2"
        }, {
          "label": "Brown",
          "value": "3"
        },{
          "label": "Black",
          "value": "4"
        }
      ],
      "validation": yup.string().required("Minimum discolouration value is required"),
      //"disabled": true
    },
    {
      "type": "comment",
      "name": "describe_your_symptoms_here",
      "label": "Describe your symptoms here",
      "validation": yup.string().min(8, 'Must be at least 8 characters').max(20, 'Must be less  than 20 characters').required("Text field is required"),
      "placeholder": "Text field",
      //"disabled": true,
      "charLimit": 700,           
    },
  ],
  "buttons": [
    {
      "color": "primary",
      "variant": "contained",
      "type": "reset",
      "label": "Reset",
    },
    {
      "color": "secondary",
      "variant": "contained",
      "type": "submit",
      "label": "Submit",
    }
  ]      
}
```

--

made a new fiddle - but the user would say/type a field label - which we would have to lookup in the schema as a field name - and we wont know the options of the field name - until its been confirmed.

https://jsfiddle.net/t7jaL0yq/

---

18th July

so this will match change my - and give the rest of the sentence -- the field label could be more than one word

```
    let triggerOne = "(?<=\\bchange my )(\\w+)"
const found3 = text.match(triggerOne);
console.log("found3", found3);


    let triggerTwo = "(?<=\\bchange my )(\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)+)"
const found4 = text.match(triggerTwo);
console.log("found4", found4);
```

[image]

Comment: Inside a string, `\b` means the backspace character. You need two backslashes (`'\\b'`) or [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) (`String.raw\`\b\``).

Comment: There is a mix of questions, updates to the question, new updated fiddle. I am lost. Can you rewrite your question to be precise as what your input is, what the expected output is, and what you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
textAnalysis(text) {
  console.log("text", text);
  const fieldNames = ["pain level", "swelling", "wound opening"];
  const fieldOptions = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

  const fieldNameRegex = new RegExp(`\\b(${fieldNames.join("|")})\\b`, "i");
  const fieldValueRegex = new RegExp(`\\b(${fieldOptions.join("|")})\\b`, "i");

  const fieldNameMatch = text.match(fieldNameRegex);
  const fieldValueMatch = text.match(fieldValueRegex);

  if (fieldNameMatch && fieldValueMatch) {
    const fieldName = fieldNameMatch[0];
    const fieldValue = fieldValueMatch[0];

    const obj = { name: fieldName, value: fieldValue };
    console.log(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: -- we wont know the field options for that specific field - until they have said it -- really the person would type or say a field label -- which we then have to get as a field name. - made a fiddle of it -https://jsfiddle.net/t7jaL0yq/

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I'll check your new code